# apply kinectjs to regular canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

So I have a fairly well established **[paint app](http://ryansaxe.info/javascriptpaint)** using HTML5 canvas! It has painting, erasing, undoing, etc. I would like to be able to add **dynamic** images, text, and shapes (drag and drop abilities as well as easy manipulation).

I just came across the KinectJS library, and it would be perfect!!! The only issue that I have is that I would rather not rewrite my entire application for KinectJS as this is for a container, not a `canvas` tag.

## question:

Is there any way to add KineticJS layers/stages into a `canvas` tag so that they still can be made with Kinetic and have the different options, but my app will still function?

## alternative:

I understand that this could be impossible...if this is so, can I apply my regular canvas functions to a Kinetic container so that the whole thing is in the kinetic container, but I do not need to rewrite the code.

## note:

If both of the above are impossible, please explain why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know the answer is no.

Kineticjs create the canvas DOM element within the container you give that is why most people use a div element as the container and that is why if you directly put a canvas it won't work. The thing is, it shouldn't change much of your code. You'll just have to call `getCanvas().getElement()` instead of your normal reference to the canvas and all your previous code will work.
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6B4q/4/) of it.

Comment: You realize that fiddle doesn't work, right? I Would love to be able to do exactly what you demonstrated, but it seems as though that doesn't actually work...